# Windows Server 2008 Not finding recently added files

Tags: indexing

Recently I am having an issue at work where users cannot search for PDF's added from January of this year and on. I have all the folders indexed, I have tried installing the File Indexing and the Windows Search server roles and I have checked that the correct iFilters are installed. I have also rebuilt the index, twice. We are able to search for files in a folder titled 2015 but nothing in 2016 shows up. Some files in 2015 are added from this year and they can be searched.

Any ideas as to what could be causing it?

EDIT: I am searching by partial file name, i.e. 567 in 123-4-567-890

Comment: I am just wondering if the search is based on the file name or the file contents?

Comment: The search is being done by file name, i.e. searching for say 567 in 123-4-567

Comment: You sure they saved them on the server ?

Comment: Yes. I am sure they are on the server.

Comment: Where are they then ? as it could be on an offline's file storage on the computer of the user

Comment: They are on a network share on a server. It is not on the users computer.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was.

Files were being named like the following: 123.456.789012

Anything after the 2nd dot would NOT show up UNLESS there was a space after: 123.456.789 012